# Can not get Appium with Expo working on device or emulator (is this even possible?)

Tags: react-native, tdd, appium, expo

I am failing to get Appium working with Expo locally. I found several sources online that tell me this should work somehow but noone explains how. When I start the webdriverio with my config I get the following error:

`ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: TypeError: Cannot read property 'capabilities' of null at Runner.run`

appium-doctor tells me that everything is fine, the android emulator and the appium server via desktop app is running and this is my wdio.conf.js:

```
  runner: 'local',
  port: 4723,

  path: '/',
  specs: ['./tests/*.js'],

  exclude: [
  ],

  maxInstances: 10,

  capabilities: [
    {
      automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
      deviceName: 'Pixel_3a_XL_API_28', // This is name of your Simulator
      platformName: 'Android',
      platformVersion: '9.0', // Android version of Simulator
      orientation: 'PORTRAIT',
      maxInstances: 1,
      app: 'appiumtest',
      // absolute path to the apk goes here ^, I'm keeping it at
      // root directory of this test project.
      noReset: true,
      newCommandTimeout: 240,
    },
  ],

  logLevel: 'info',

  bail: 0,

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost',

  waitforTimeout: 10000,

  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,

  connectionRetryCount: 3,

  services: ['chromedriver', 'appium'],


  appium: {

  },

  framework: 'jasmine',

  reporters: ['spec'],

  jasmineNodeOpts: {

    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,

    expectationResultHandler: function(passed, assertion) {

    },
  },


};
``
```

Comment: can you share the code that's making an instance of the driver? Sounding like it's missing this config file all together

Comment: Unfortunatly I can not repdroduce this error since I changed too much to figure this out ;)